# Embedding Cordova WebView, Receiver is not registered

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-fragmentactivity

I have embedded the Cordova WebvView as a component to my project, everything works fine except one thing; when the back button is pressed I get an error on LogCat which says "Receiver Not Registered !" I dont think I have registered a receiver. There is also a sample project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/stevengill/CordovaActionView). I also get the same error when I run this application.

What I want to do is, embed Cordova WebView into my Android project and run some javascript functions.

Here is my main activity;

```
public class MainNativeViewController extends FragmentActivity implements CordovaInterface,
    JavaScriptListener {

FragmentTransaction transaction;
RelativeLayout childBrowser;
RelativeLayout dialogBox;
RelativeLayout emailComposer;

private ExecutorService threadPool;

CordovaWebViewFragment cordovaWebViewFragment;

public CordovaWebView cordovaWebView;

public LayoutInflater inflater;
CordovaPlugin mActivityResultCallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

    threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    cordovaWebView = SingleTonCordovaWebView.getCordovaWebView(this);
    cordovaWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/invoke_native_view.html");

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();

    manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, listFragment).commit();
}

@Override
public void showFragment(String fragmentName) {

    /*
     * This method is used to create and replace a fragment to the
     * container. according to name passed through here.
     */

    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left,
            R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

    if (fragmentName.equals("error")) {
        DialogCreator dialog = new DialogCreator(this);
        dialog.createDialog("Error !", "Fragment Name is wrong,", "Check fragment name", false);
    } else {
        // fragment name is ignored for different cases, it will be used for
        // further proporties.
        // Just checking out the error in the case its not right parameter.

        NativeViewTestFragment testFragment = new NativeViewTestFragment(fragmentName);

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, testFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    // Forward to plugins
    if ((this.cordovaWebView != null) && (this.cordovaWebView.pluginManager != null)) {
        this.cordovaWebView.pluginManager.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void cancelLoadUrl() {

}

@Override
public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
    return threadPool;
}

@Override
public Activity getActivity() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public Context getContext() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public Object onMessage(final String id, final Object data) {
    // return getCordovaFragment().onMessage(id, data);
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin plugin, Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    mActivityResultCallback = plugin;
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}

@Override
/**
 * Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity.
 */
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Send pause event to JavaScript
    this.cordovaWebView.loadUrl("javascript:try{cordova.fireDocumentEvent('pause');}catch(e){console.log('exception firing pause event from native');};");

    // Forward to plugins
    if (this.cordovaWebView.pluginManager != null) {
        this.cordovaWebView.pluginManager.onPause(true);
    }
    threadPool.shutdown();
    threadPool = null;
}

@Override
/**
 * Called when the activity will start interacting with the user.
 */
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    if (this.cordovaWebView == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Send resume event to JavaScript
    this.cordovaWebView
            .loadUrl("javascript:try{cordova.fireDocumentEvent('resume');}catch(e){console.log('exception firing resume event from native');};");

    // Forward to plugins
    if (this.cordovaWebView.pluginManager != null) {
        this.cordovaWebView.pluginManager.onResume(true);
    }       
}

@Override
/**
 * The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed.
 */
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (cordovaWebView.pluginManager != null) {
        cordovaWebView.pluginManager.onDestroy();
    }

    if (this.cordovaWebView != null) {

        // Send destroy event to JavaScript
        this.cordovaWebView
                .loadUrl("javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};");

        // Load blank page so that JavaScript onunload is called
        this.cordovaWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");

        // Forward to plugins
        if (this.cordovaWebView.pluginManager != null) {
            this.cordovaWebView.pluginManager.onDestroy();
        }
    } else {
        // this.endActivity();
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is the LogCat output;

```
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     destroy activity     {org.apache.cordova.example/okan.apps.nativeview.MainNativeViewController}:     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:     org.apache.cordova.Device$1@45391938
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3655)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: org.apache.cordova.Device$1@45391938
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:793)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:814)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at org.apache.cordova.Device.onDestroy(Device.java:98)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.onDestroy(PluginManager.java:317)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at okan.apps.nativeview.MainNativeViewController.onDestroy(MainNativeViewController.java:204)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
11-23 12:25:36.117: E/AndroidRuntime(9645):     ... 11 more
```

**EDIT:**

I ended up with a solution. I was using Cordova Web View in a Fragment, I moved it out from fragment and put it into same xml with fragment container. Now it works without error. Its the same in the sample project in the GitHub, CordovaWebView is in FrameLayout.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this in my fragment by adding the following to onDestroyView()

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mCordovaWebView.handleDestroy();

    }
```

Comment: Not sure which version of Cordova you are using but (It's probably solved in the newer versions), that time, when I asked that question, Your solution didn't work.

Comment: I'm using 3.6.4 on Android.   However, my solution above seems to have introduced ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: org.apache.cordova.App```  on exiting...


I ended up here because using the back button to finish the app was giving me the ```Activity MainNativeViewController has leaked IntentReceiver org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView$1@45376528 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()```


Which seems to be the reverse of what you were originally seeing.

Comment: If you see that exception then it's the same problem after adding @Yoel 's solution above. So instead of using onDestroy if you call handleDestroy in onDestroyView solves the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement the whole destroy flow yourself, you can use the following:

```
public void onDestroy() {
  LOG.d("Destroying the View", "onDestroy()");
  super.onDestroy();

  if (this.cwv != null) {
    this.cwv.handleDestroy();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but I still get the same error. it says,

`Activity MainNativeViewController has leaked IntentReceiver org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView$1@45376528 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?`

Comment: Hey I guess I found the way, I called `this.cwv.removeAllViews();`
before handleDestroy(), It seems it works. I dont get the error anymore but I don't know its the right way ?

Comment: **EDIT : **In this way it gets destroyed without error but In the case I try to start the app again after destroying it then I get another error, which says, `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"`

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this?